# Highcharts: Column chart has banding as a result of inconsistent spacing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a column chart which has a mass of data (approximately 300+ entries) and I seem to be getting a visual banding as a result of the data being incorrectly spaced.

I've tried the following `plotOptions` setting:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointInterval: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'between',
            pointRange: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    }
```

Reading the API, I was under the impression `pointPadding` being set to 0 would resolve the issue however I am still seeing that very slight padding on every 7th data point.

Depending on your screen size, you can see the issue here in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neilff/WcLSg/4/

Is there a way to explicitly state how far each column should be spaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have set `pointPadding`, but then you have set `pointWidth` which will overwrite `pointPadding`. Simply disable `pointWidth`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/WcLSg/5/

Comment: Ah, I stated my issue incorrectly... I actually do want padding, I just want it to be consistent. It seems to be adding a consistent padding for every 7 bars, and then the 8th has additional padding so it creates a banding effect.

Comment: Okay, let's consider your example: your chart has e.g. width=600px. Then you set for each bar 1px width. And you have 301 bars. It's not possible to divide space into even bars. You can set instead width for xAxis, see: http://jsfiddle.net/WcLSg/10/